# How to call app.post('/deletemsg') inside app.post('/deletemsg') in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

Anyone help me..I am new in nodejs ..how to call one route inside another route.doing some query in getmsg route and result of the first one calling text route deletemsg..

```
app.post('/getmsg', function (req, res) {
  app.post('/deletemsg',{id:2});//need to call this 
}
app.post('/deletemsg', function (req, res) { //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, put a function in the route `/deletemsg`

```
app.post('/getmsg', function (req, res) {
  getCalled(req,res,{id:2});//pass req, res and the object you want to send
}

app.post('/deletemsg',getCalled)  // pass function here

function getCalled(req, res, obj) { 

//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not a gud trick if you want to delete column with app.post
you need to send id with body object the get look like this

```
$http.post('/getmsg',{id:2})
 .success(function(success){
  //do  someting with success response
  })
 .error(function(err){
 //do somthing with err response
 })
```

and server should be like this (as [NoDownvotesPlz suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071837/how-to-call-app-post-deletemsg-inside-app-post-deletemsg-in-nodejs-expre/29071879#29071879)):

```
app.post('/getmsg', function (req, res) {
 var id  = req.body.id;
 getCalled(req,res,id);//pass req, res and the object you want to send
}

app.post('/deletemsg',getCalled)  // pass function here

function getCalled(req, res, obj) { 

//do something
}
```