# How can I call app.post method from app.js without going to browser and run the file url-node js?

Tags: node.js, express

How can I call `app.post` method from app.js without going to browser and run the file url-node js?

Comment: You want to call post from within your application?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071837/how-to-call-app-post-deletemsg-inside-app-post-deletemsg-in-nodejs-expre

Comment: I used node package 'ajax-request' to solve problem